# How to have Jest findRelatedTests refer to all files in a folder and ignore a particular file?

Tags: regex, jestjs

For example, I want to have all js files in the folder **app** to be included when I find related tests, and I'd like to exclude one file let's say its name is **exclude.js**, how would I write my Jest command?

```
jest --findRelatedTests FILE_PATH_PATTERN_REGEX_I_WANT_TO_KNOW
```

Here's my try

```
jest --findRelatedTests dir/s/b app\*.js | find /v "exclude.js"
```

The windoes dir command part seems to work, but I wasn't quite sure how to get this to be treated as an argument when I run the jest command.

Also, is it possible to combine **findRelatedTests** with **changedSince**?

It's kind of confusing how **jest -o** works. Based on the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli), I thought that it runs the related tests of uncommited files, so it should behave like **findRelatedTests** + **changedSince**. But I did jest -o and it runs everything even though my repo didn't have any changes compared to the previous revision.